# food information graph modeling

Tags: database-design, neo4j

I've the following information from a mongodb db that I want to export to a neo4j graph:

```
"_id" : 1366,
"fields" : {
"title" : "Beef Steak",
"keywords" : [
    "beef",
    "steak"
],
"categories" : {
    "category" : "Meat",
    "subcategory" : null,
    "verified" : false,
    "predicted" : true
 },
 "nutrients" :
    {
        "tag_name" : "FASAT",
        "value" : 1.352,
        "unit" : "g",
        "title" : "Saturated fatty acids"
    },
    ...
```

I've been reading some neo4j modelling examples but I'm not sure about my model.

This is what I'm thinking:

Nodes:

- food
- keyword
- category
- subcategory
- nutrient

Relationships:

1. food - rel_name -> keyword
2. food - rel_name -> category
3. food - rel_name -> subcategory
4. category - rel_name -> subcategory
5. food - has_nutrients -> nutrient

The "has_nutrients" relationship name would contain a "value" property to indicate how much of a nutrient a food has.

I thought about 2,3 and 4 relationships to have the possibility to perform different queries: - subcategories of the category 'Meat', - category and subcategory of a food, -all the foods with the 'Pasta' category. Maybe there's a more simple way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't think of better names for the relations, just do something like

```
food - [HAS_KEYWORD] -> keyword
food - [HAS_SUBCATEGORY] -> subcategory
subcategory - [BELONGS_TO] -> category
food - [HAS_NUTRIENT] -> nutrient
```

For your subcategory, I typically like a direction from child to parent, but I that's usually more just preference.

Will you need to differentiate between category and subcategory? Like if category is `Meat` and subcategory is `Pork`, would you ever need to do actually link to `Meat`? You could have just a connection to `Pork` and that would imply `Meat` to cut down on relationships.

```
({name='Pork', type='Subcategory'}) -[BELONGS_TO]-> ({name='Meat', type='Category'})
({name='Pork Chops', type='Food'}) -[HAS_SUBCATEGORY]-> ({name='Pork', type='Subcategory'})
```

This will cut down on relationships, as you'll be able to imply a Category from a Subcategory.

Aside from the above recommendations, The rest looks very graph oriented and looks like a solid design.